# concatenating varchar on query returns even less result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in php with a mysql database.

```
SELECT address+','+ city+','+ zipcode FROM client;
```

which returns `123`

currently there is only 1 entry in the table, but in this entry just address alone is `123 main street`

why is the query getting cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you should use `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate strings with separator (plus `+` is for arithmetic operations) :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', address, city, zipcode) FROM client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(address,',',city,',',zipcode) FROM client;
```